# Kayaking with orcas around Vancouver Island, BC: Finding places and kayak rentals

Tags: rental, british-columbia, vancouver-island, canoeing-and-kayaking, whalewatching

I will be travelling to Vancouver Island, BC in June and would like, if possible, to kayak in the presence of orcas.

How can I find out if there are any good spots with a high chance to see orcas around the island? What can I do to learn about renting kayaks and going for a tour by ourselves? I am not interested in organized group trips.

I checked online but I can find either multi-days organized kayak tours or whale watching tours from boats.

Any suggestions for how I can learn about about equipment to bring and any "not-to-do" tips when you encounter orcas in the water?

Comment: Why are you not interested in organized group trips? Group trips come with a guide, and a guide is going to be key to finding orcas. Would you be OK with hiring a guide just for your party?

Comment: Hey @DJClayworth, thank you for your reply. Organized group trips can be tricky, since you can be in the same group as people at different kayaking levels and with different needs, which is OK but not ideal. I like your idea to hire a guide, I hadn't thought about it! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Or go with a multi-day group that pretty much requires a high level of kayaking experience by virtue of its length and location.